# Map tiling service with more recent imagery

Tags: tiles, mapbox, imagery, tile-map-service

I am using MapBox for mapping in a SaaS product. I've noticed that some (all) of the imagery is older than what I would ideally want. Is there a way to upgrade to more up-to-date imagery into the MapBox tiling service? Is there another tiling service that has (or you can upgrade to) more recent imagery (and integrate into a dashboard)?

Comment: See https://www.maptiler.com/satellite/

Comment: Would Planet or Maxar be too expensive? Eox could be cheaper but not as up-to-date alternative http://maps.eox.at/.

Comment: Thanks to both for the thoughts. I will take a look and see if they will fit my needs!